# I connected apache 4433,8012 and mysql 8012 but phpmyadmin says I don't have enough permissions

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

[image]
I connected apache 4433,8012 and mysql 8012 but phpmyadmin says I don't have enough permissions.
I just tried to open phpmyadmin with xampp but phpmyadmin says i don't have enough access rights even though apache and mysql both work.

I tried changing other ports but still no access. Please help me

Comment: This is about the user access rights and nothing to do with ports.